# Why the head is copied on the body?

Tags: html, ajax

When I use this HTML template in my server, the head is copied on the body. I get in

```
 <table id="myTable">
```

the whole head repeated.

```
<title>IndoorLoc App</title>
```

That title tag is the first that appears after the table tag and I don't understand wht thid happens and following that comes all the head tag including js scripts.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IndoorLoc App</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function ajax(){
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                }
            }
            req.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/data', true);
            req.send();
        }
        setInterval(function(){ajax();}, 1000);
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="head">
            <h1>IndoorLoc</h1>
        </header>
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <td>MAC address</td>
                <td>RSSI</td>
            </tr>
            %for row in rows1:
            <tr>
                <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
                <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
            </tr>
            %end
            <tr>
                <td>MAC address</td>
                <td>RSSI</td>
            </tr>
            %for row in rows2:
            <tr>
                <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
                <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
            </tr>
            %end
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is being "repeated"?  Note also that you're using AJAX to request new data and update the HTML when the code executes.  What is that data?  If the data you're writing to the table has a `<title>` element then, well, the data you're writing to the table has a `<title>` element.  Is that the case?

Comment: Does your `req.responseText;` contains `<tr>` tags too? Or it's just content of some data? What does it contains? Have you tried inspecting HTML generated?

Comment: The only data that is being updated is the one inside id=MyTable on the table tag. What is repeated is all the head tag on the body tag. So I get the head tag twice, one is the actual head tag and a head tag inside the body tag having the title tag after id="Mytable" following with the whole head tag.

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting and directly inserting inside table tag, what kind of data is that, If it is table body markup then it will work otherwise it will just add string or response whatever you are getting.

Comment: That data comes from a python script that passes content from a database. But the problem is that I get the whole head tag in the body tag